# Ember Data - Assign a value inside an object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm starting up with ember and trying to get some data from an Api and assign it to an Emberjs model.

My api returns something like:

```
    [
    {
        email: 'someemail@domain.com'
        name: {
            firstname: 'first name',
            lastname: 'last name'
        }
    }
    {
        email: 'someemail2@domain.com'
        name: {
            firstname: 'another first name',
            lastname: 'another last name'
        }
    },
    {
        email: 'someemail3@domain.com'
        name: undefined
    }

]
```

And my code is:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
});

App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Users', DS.Adapter.extend({
  findAll: function(store, type, id) {
    $.getJSON('https://domain.com/users?callback=?', {
        'auth_token': token
    }).done(function(json){
        store.loadMany(type, json);
    });
  },
}));

App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Users', DS.Adapter.extend({
  findAll: function(store, type, id) {
    $.getJSON('https://domain.com/users?callback=?', {
        'auth_token': token
    }).done(function(json){
        store.loadMany(type, json);
    });
  },
}));

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("users", { path: "/users" });
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Users.find();
  }
});

App.Users = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    didLoad: function() {
        console.log('model loaded', this.toJSON());
    }
});


 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
    {{#each model}}
        {{email}} - {{firstname}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Obviously firstname is empty for every object in the array.

Does anyone know what's the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up your User model like this:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.User', {
  name: {embedded: 'always'}
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.belongsTo('App.UserName')
});

App.UserName = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Hi Mokane, thanks for your answer. I tried it but i get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_create' of undefined" error. i think it may be due to some models having name set to null (no name available). Any idea?

Comment: I also think the uncaught error might be due to some models having name set to null, can you intercept the models and set something in name only to be sure?

Comment: Thanks Mokane I eddited the answer to show one of the problematic objects.

Comment: can you test if the error is also happening if the embedded objects have "name" set to "{}" instead of undefined... can you interfere the json payload to test it?

Comment: I think it may be complaining because I'm not assigning all the elements from the json to the model. I'll get back to you on this. Thanks